# How to connect to mongo database in heroku from ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, heroku, amazon-ec2

I am working on Ruby on Rails app with Mongodb .My app is deployed on heroku and for delayed jobs i am using amazon ec2. Things I have a doubt

1)How to connect to the mongo database in amazon ec2 which is basically at heroku?
2)When i run delayed jobs how it will went to amazon server what are the changes i have to make to the app?  If somebody can point me tutorial for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make your EC2 instance visible to your application on Heroku, you need to add your instance to Heroku's security group from Amazon. There are some instructions in Heroku's documentation that explain how to connect to external services like this.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#connecting-to-external-services

In the case of MongoDB running on its default ports, you'd want to do something like this:

```
$ ec2-authorize YOURGROUP -P tcp -p 27017 -u 098166147350 -o default
```

As for how to handle your delayed jobs running remotely on the EC2 instance, you might find this article from the Artsy engineering team helpful. It sounds like they developed a fairly similar setup.

http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/01/31/beyond-heroku-satellite-delayed-job-workers-on-ec2/